# Trying to make the code readable

Tags: iphone, c, xcode, c-preprocessor

I am trying to create a define like this

```
#define ICONS   [NSArray arrayWithObjects: [NSNumber numberWithFloat:33.0f], [NSNumber numberWithFloat:93.0f], [NSNumber numberWithFloat:149.0f], [NSNumber numberWithFloat:205.0f], [NSNumber numberWithFloat:314.0f], [NSNumber numberWithFloat:370.0f], [NSNumber numberWithFloat:426.0f], [NSNumber numberWithFloat:482.0f], nil]
```

but, I would like to write it organized in lines - to make the code readable, like

```
#define ICONS   [NSArray arrayWithObjects: 
[NSNumber numberWithFloat:33.0f], 
[NSNumber numberWithFloat:93.0f], 
[NSNumber numberWithFloat:149.0f], 
[NSNumber numberWithFloat:205.0f], 
[NSNumber numberWithFloat:314.0f],
[NSNumber numberWithFloat:370.0f],
[NSNumber numberWithFloat:426.0f],
[NSNumber numberWithFloat:482.0f],
nil]
```

but when I break the define in lines, Xcode yells like mad.

Is there a way to break the line and organize the code as I want?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To split a #define across lines you need to append `\` to the lines.

```
#define ICONS   [NSArray arrayWithObjects:               \
                    [NSNumber numberWithFloat:33.0f],    \
                    [NSNumber numberWithFloat:93.0f],    \
                    [NSNumber numberWithFloat:149.0f],   \ 
                    [NSNumber numberWithFloat:205.0f],   \
                    [NSNumber numberWithFloat:314.0f],   \
                    [NSNumber numberWithFloat:370.0f],   \
                    [NSNumber numberWithFloat:426.0f],   \
                    [NSNumber numberWithFloat:482.0f],   \
                    nil]
```

Answer (score 2):

Per the C spec, multiline defines need a '\' at the end of each line:

```
#define ICONS   [NSArray arrayWithObjects: \
                    [NSNumber numberWithFloat:33.0f],  \
                    [NSNumber numberWithFloat:93.0f],  \
                    [NSNumber numberWithFloat:149.0f], \
                    [NSNumber numberWithFloat:205.0f], \
                    [NSNumber numberWithFloat:314.0f], \
                    [NSNumber numberWithFloat:370.0f], \
                    [NSNumber numberWithFloat:426.0f], \
                    [NSNumber numberWithFloat:482.0f], \
                    nil]
```